# Changing multiple images with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here is the JQuery I am using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ltwitch').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tnick+".json?callback=?", function(c) {
            if (c.stream == null) {
                span.html("Offline");
            } else {
                span.html("Online");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And the HTML that was with it when I found it

```
<a class="ltwitch" href="http://www.twitch.tv/ifstudios" data-tnick="IFStudios">IFStudios</a> (<span>...</span>)
```

RoosterTeeth (...)

Now what I want to do, I have HTML that looks like this

```
<a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/sweet.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
```

Basically when a channel becomes live I want to switch the img src from the image I have it set to, to the same image with -online on the end. So I can have multiple pictures on the website, but I can have the images change dependent on who is live and who isn't.

So if I have

```
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/sweet.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
```

When her channel goes live, it will turn to

```
                    <a href="#portfolioModal3" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/portfolio/sweet-online.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

Or if it was

```
 <img src="img/portfolio/carrot.png"
```

it would turn to

```
 <img src="img/portfolio/carrot-online.png"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question? Write a function that gets `image.src` of the appropriate element, inserts `-online` into it, and writes it back to `image.src`.

Comment: Basically I just want it to check to see if the channel is online and add -online to the end of the existing image, or remove it if the channel returns "null" when it checks. Or, just set the image for the hole thing if I can't do that.

Comment: I know what you want to do, that's not a question. Please show your attempt to implement it, and explain the problem you're having with it. Then we'll try to help you fix it.

Comment: I just ended up using the base code to add in a status banner. I am just not good enough at coding to be able to add in pictures, I am not sure how to call to it. I am trying my best :/ I will update if I figure it out :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ltwitch').each(function () {
        var tnick = $(this).data('tnick');
        var span = $(this).next();
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+tnick+".json?callback=?", function(c) {
            var img = $(img-selector);
            var source = img.attr('src');
            if (c.stream != null) {
                // Online
                if(source.indexOf('.png') != -1){
                    source = source.replace(".png", "-online.png");
                    img.attr('src',source);
                }
            }
            else{
                // Offline
                source.replace("-online", "");
                img.attr('src',source);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: You have to pass the correct image selector to `$(img-selector)`. Also call the same function again for refreshing

Comment: To add `-online`, you could just do `source.replace(".png", "-online.png");` (just like you do when you remove the `-online`, no need for slicing)